# Trigger UPDATE escrever arquivo TXT

Tags: sql-server, trigger

Como posso criar uma trigger que é disparada toda vez que tiver um `UPDATE` em x coluna, pegar o novo valor criar novo arquivo txt e inserir dentro dele. ( para fins de sincronização ).

Por exemplo:

`produtos`

```
Layout do txt:
55 | nome_produto | quantidadeEstoque | peso
```

Em eventos de updates, ele pega alguns valores e insere neste layout em um novo txt.

Até a parte da trigger e etc eu criei, porém, não sei como trabalhar com a manipulação de `TXT`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O método mais conhecido é [criar uma trigger comum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) e usar o comando [`master..xp_cmdshell`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx) para executar algum comando qualquer no ambiente do sistema operacional que, por sua vez, grave os dados no arquivo e local desejados.

Eis alguns métodos para criar o arquivo texto baseados [neste aritgo](http://www.nigelrivett.net/SQLTsql/WriteTextFile.html):

### **BCP**

É uma ferramenta do SQL que executa uma query e escreve para um arquivo texto. Exemplo:

```sql
master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp banco..tabela out c:\arquivo.bcp -S -U -P -c '
```

### Redirecionamento da saída para um arquivo

É basicamente usar comandos do sistema opperacional para gerar o arquivo. Exemplo:

```sql
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'echo meu-texto-aqui > c:\arquivo.txt'
```

Note que é possível chamar qualquer programa e passar algum valor usando uma variável, por exemplo.

## Considerações

**Utilizar uma trigger para gravar em um arquivo é uma péssima ideia**, pois você estará afetando diretamente o desempenho do banco de dados e, consequentemente, do sistema, fora o tempo de resposta ao usuário.

Uma solução alternativa é gravar os dados em uma tabela auxiliar ou utilizar uma flag de controle para depois exportar os dados novos em uma tarefa executada periodicamente, por exemplo, a cada N minutos.

Comment: Precisa ser em txt, para jogar em um FTP e sincronizar com uma loja virtual. Então pensei na maneira da trigger rodar, toda vez que tiver um update no campo que preciso, montar o txt e jogar em um diretório. Não terei problema com performance pois é pouca demanda. Li sobbre o comando xp_cmdshell, consigo montar o txt com ele, porém, como faço para ele criar o txt? Ele apenas insere o conteúdo se o arquivo já existe, se não existe me retorna permissão negada. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Consegui rodar o comando em outro diretório, usando > ele cria, usando >> ele reescreve. Obrigado pela ajuda amigo, tentarei fazer adaptação com a trigger aqui e ver como fica em produção, qualquer coisa do um retorno!